# Retain css float when using jQuery animate to slide left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having css issues when using jQuery's animate. I have tried a few methods to get this working but to no avail. Basically all I'm trying to do is have a side bar slide left and right via a click event but it seems the css (float) is causing issues. I know exactly the problem but not sure how to exactly fix it. Rather than me trying to explain the problem i have reproduced it with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/70hq1ky2/

The main content(article) seems to dip for milliseconds because it has the float style.

```
<a href='#' class='slide-side'>Slide</a>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
<aside  data-side-bar="open"></aside>
<article></article>

$('.slide-side').click(function (e)
    {
        var asideWidth = $("aside").width();
        var isOpen = $('aside').attr("data-side-bar");
        if (isOpen == "open") {
            $('aside').animate({ marginLeft: '-=' + asideWidth });
            $('article').animate({ width: '100%',});
            $('aside').attr("data-side-bar", "close");
        }
        else if (isOpen == "close")
        {

            $('aside').animate({ width: '20%', marginLeft: '0' });
            $('article').animate({ width: '80%' });
            $('aside').attr("data-side-bar", "open");
        }
    });
```

Any help greatly appreciated! On pointers on writing this better is certainly most welcome.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having your object have CSS of `float: left` or right or whatever, using absolute positioning. For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar">
    Woo sidebar content.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100px; /* top offset */
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
hideSidebar = function(){
    $("#sidebar").animate(
        {
             left: "-100px"
        },
        500
    }
}
```

Therefore all I need to do is set the `left` attribute in jQuery to the negative width of the div, and it disappears, then setting it back to 0 will make it appear again. This is, of course, assuming you want the sidebar on the left side, otherwise use `right` instead of `left`.

Also note that if you want the sidebar to follow the user as they navigate through your application, you can also set `position: fixed` instead, so it follows the user as they scroll.

Comment: I'm starting realise that using position rather than float works with jQuery better. Never the less great simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make slight change in your script make +5 for aside

```
$('.slide-side').click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var asideWidth = $("aside").width();
        var isOpen = $('aside').attr("data-side-bar");
        if (isOpen == "open") {
            $('aside').animate({ marginLeft: '-=' + asideWidth+5});
            $('article').animate({ width: '100%',});
            $('aside').attr("data-side-bar", "close");
        }
        else if (isOpen == "close")
        {

            $('aside').animate({ width: '20%', marginLeft: '0' });
            $('article').animate({ width: '80%' });
            $('aside').attr("data-side-bar", "open");
        }
    });
```